# Javascript/CSS slow motion menu on IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a sort of menu in a project that I'm working to, that is used in IE7 browsers only.
HTML:

```
<table class="tabellaquad" cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=1">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            ONE
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=7">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            1
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=4">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            RED
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=2">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            TWO
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=8">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            2
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=5">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            BLUE
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=3">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            THREE
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=9">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            3
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=6">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            YELLOW
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
       <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=10">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            4
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="item" href="index.jsp?quad=11">
        <div align="center" class="tabquad">
            5
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.tabellaquad{
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:40%;
text-align:center;
}

.tabquad{
color:white;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
border:2px solid #000;
border-color:rgb(82,115,154);
width:200px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
top:25px;
background-color:rgb(0,56,130);
}
.tabquad:hover{
background-color:rgb(49,87,132);
cursor: hand;
}
```

What I would like to do is having 3 "father" button (a `<div>`), for each column. When I click on one of them, the buttons must appear slowly under it (depending on the column).

Is there any CSS/JS script that I can use for doing this? My main issue is that I have to use IE7, I googled for something, not finding anything useful.

Here you can find some [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKG8w/) example.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't yet, check out JqueryUI. I found it easy to pick up and it takes care of almost all of the underlying detail of css and animation for you.

http://jqueryui.com/
http://api.jqueryui.com/

It also takes care of almost all of the multi-browser issues you might have.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent on Javascript?

Comment: Ok how about this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423633/javascript-dropdown-menus?rq=1) already on stack which ultimately leads to: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: any news about this Question?